# I am in the US on an ESTA, with work

Tags: usa, canada, esta, uk-citizens

Can I drive across the Canadian border for a day, or do I need another form of permit?

I obviously have and would take my UK passport.

Comment: What do you mean by “with work"? On a business visit? Working for a US employer?

Answer (score 2):

It's very unclear from your question what you are doing, but let me lay out the salient points. Assuming you are in the US legitimately:

- As a UK citizen you are permitted to enter Canada without a visa for short visits. If you show up at the border you should be let in.
- Likewise the US will permit you to return after your trip to Canada without any other kind of permit.
- However, if you are nearing the end of your permitted period of time in the US, a day trip to Canada will NOT reset the clock. Your permitted length of stay will be as if you had not left the US.